# How to enable Item on click in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, disable

I have a list of subsections in my dialog container. I'm trying make all of them disabled when the dialog is open and only enabled selected subsection when the pencil icon is click for that subsection.

For example....

when user click subsection 1 pencil icon

Subsection 1 enabled

Subsection 2 disabled

Subsection 3 disabled. ....

and process will be the same for subsection 2 and 3. Any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

```
<p class="substyle">Subsections</p>
<div class="substyle" *ngFor="let subsection of section.subSections">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <input matInput(ngModelChange)="nameChanged({newValue: $event, 
        isSection: false, id: subsection.id} 
        [(ngModel)]="subsection.sectionName">
   </mat-form-field>

<button mat-icon-button color="primary" 
    (click)="editDoc(subsection)"> <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>

<button mat-icon-button (click)="openConfirmDialog(subsection, false)" 
    *ngIf="isSubsection"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
</button>
```

TS

```
// THis is called when pencil icon is click
  editDoc(value) {
    this.subsectionToEdit = value;
    this.refreshEditor = false;
  }

// Delete Subsections
      this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
        const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.parentId);
        if (~index) {
          this.mappedSections[index].subSections = this.mappedSections[index].subSections.filter((subsection) => subsection.id != sec.id)
        }
      })
```

[image]

Comment: Does each subsection have an id or something unique tied to it?

Comment: Hi DJ, yes.. each subsection have uniqued id but they have the same SectionId/ParentId (Picture Updated and also code ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

In the `input` bind the `[disabled]` attribute to a `boolean`, like I have below:

```
<p class="substyle">Subsections</p>
<div class="substyle" *ngFor="let subsection of section.subSections">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <input [disabled] = "subsection.id !== selectedId" matInput style="width: 200px; height: 15px;" type="text"
       (ngModelChange)="nameChanged({newValue: $event, isSection: false, id: subsection.id})"
       [(ngModel)]="subsection.sectionName">
   </mat-form-field>

<button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Edit documents for this Subsection"
   style="bottom: 10px;" (click)="editDoc(subsection)"> <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>

<button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Delete this 
    Subsection" (click)="openConfirmDialog(subsection, false)" 
    style="bottom: 10px;" *ngIf="isSubsection"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Then in your editDoc function, do the following:

```
  editDoc(value) {
    // make sure you make selectedId a property before doing this
    this.selectedId = value.id  // set the selectedId property to the selected value id
    this.subsectionToEdit = value;
    this.refreshEditor = false;
  }
```

So what will happen is, whenever the selectedId is set, it will set all the inputs that don't belong to the selected subsection to disable automatically.